# 1P/Halley "Tiberius" Algorithm

Tags: c#

So i started programming in college without any initiation,asumming we already know the basics, but i didn't take any c# classes before.

The exercise asks me to determine all the appearances of the Tiberius comet from the last 3000 years. This comet appears once at 75 years, 116 days, 19 hours and 12 minutes. Last time we saw it was 1986 5 february 21:29. I calculated penultimate date: 1910 285 days(october 12) 2hours:17mins. I cannot transpose this simple calculus into a proper c# programm. I need some advices, maybe some code with afferent explanation will help me more. If you can contribute, i'll be more than satisfied.

I`m thinking to convert years,days and hours to days, then substract those 75 years (already converted to minutes). This will continue before it reach 3000 years back from 1986.
75 years 116 days 19 hours and 12 minutes = 27491.8034726 days                       The year we start to count down 1986 36 days 21 hours 29 mins=724926.8951389 days                                                                                   I guess we will decrement this last number with every appearance and for every time it appeared we will print year,date,time.

Comment: Can you [express your algorithm in pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)?

Comment: A `DateTime` in .NET has lots of useful methods to add units of time.

Comment: we only work in codeblocks,unfortunately. @Chris Farmer Thanks for quick response.@EdPlunkett,i will provide pseudo-code in minutes.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett 75 years 116 days 19 hours and 12 minutes = 27491.8034726 days                       The year we start to count down 1986 36 days 21 hours 29 mins=724926.8951389 days                                                                                   I guess we will decrement this last number with every appearance and for every time it appeared we will print year,date,time.

Comment: @crt01 If that's meant as an addition to your question, please edit the question and put it there.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime and TimeSpan are useful classes for this:

```
var lastOccurrence = new DateTime(1986, 2, 5, 21, 29, 0);
var previous = lastOccurrence.AddYears(-75).AddDays(-116).AddHours(-19).AddMinutes(-12);
// Previous is now 10/12/1910 2:17:00
```

I leave the looping to go back 3,000 years as an exercise for the reader ;)

---

I had originally hoped to be able to create a TimeSpan and just use the DateTime.Subtract method, but it looks like TimeSpan doesn't have a constructor that takes years, and it probably wouldn't handle leap years correctly so I think the above is a better solution.

Comment: if previous < -1013years 365 days 23hrs 59 mins programm stops here

Comment: while previous > -1013 yrs 365 days 23 hrs 59 mins print all the dates between 1986 and -1013 else if previous < -1013years 365 days 23hrs 59 mins programm stops here